# How to resolve BadPadding exception while RSA Signing?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, jwt, rsa, badpaddingexception

I am trying to create a signed JWT , but when I try to sign he JWT I am getting the following exception,

```
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: RSA private key operation failed
        at sun.security.rsa.RSACore.crtCrypt(RSACore.java:201)
        at sun.security.rsa.RSACore.rsa(RSACore.java:122)
        at sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.engineSign(RSASignature.java:192)
        ... 74 more
```

I have a two JWK which use RS256 alg to sign the JWT. Both are of bit size 2048, but I am able to sign the JWT successfully using one among them, but not with the other.(Cant share the JWK)

I have compared both the JWK and all the required key in the JWK JSON are same but only their modulus and exponent differ.

I am unable to understand what is causing the issue.

You can replicate the issue using the fiollowing code:

```
KeyPairGenerator gen= KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        gen.initialize(2048);

        JWK sigJWK = new RSAKey.Builder((RSAPublicKey)gen.generateKeyPair().getPublic())
                .privateKey((RSAPrivateKey)gen.generateKeyPair().getPrivate())
                .keyUse(KeyUse.SIGNATURE)
                .keyID("s1")
                .algorithm(JWSAlgorithm.RS256)
                .build();

        Map<String, Object> jwkParamMap = JsonUtil.parseJson(sigJWK.toString());
        PrivateKey sigKey= new RsaJsonWebKey(jwkParamMap).getRsaPrivateKey();
        String tokenEndpoint = request.getAttribute("scheme") + "://" + request.getAttribute("ip") +
                request.getAttribute("tokenurl");



        Random randomInt=new Random();
        JWTClaimsSet claims = new JWTClaimsSet.Builder()
        .issuer(clientID)
        .subject(clientID)
        .audience(tokenEndpoint)
        .jwtID("ItsmejwtID"+randomInt.nextInt())
        .expirationTime(new Date(new Date().getTime()+ 120* 1000))
        .build();

        JWSSigner signer = new RSASSASigner(sigKey);
        SignedJWT signedJWT = new SignedJWT(new JWSHeader(JWSAlgorithm.RS256), claims);
        signedJWT.sign(signer);

        return signedJWT.serialize();
```

Comment: The RSA key is inconsistent. You call `gen.generateKeyPair()` _twice_, once when passing the public key and once when passing the private key. Therefore, the public key of the first key pair is used and the private key of the second key pair, making the passed public and private key unrelated. If you apply related keys, the code works.

Comment: Oh! I did not think of that at all!! Nice catch!@Topaco . You can post the answer , ill accept it.

Comment: @Topaco Also, why does it throw bad padding exception? If there is a key mismatch, why not an error corresponding to the same, how is it that the padding is changing if both the keys are generated using 2048 bit generator.

Comment: Decryption can be performed with _any_ key, even a _wrong_ one. Of course, with a wrong key the result is wrong, including a wrong padding, which leads to the `BadPaddingException`. Why an _inconsistent_ key (the JWK generated with `sigJWK.toString()` has an n != p*q, as e.g. an OpenSSL check shows) is not recognized can only be answered by the developers of the library (maybe performance).